# Python cannot find a module while it is installed

Tags: python, module

I have a code as below:

```
#!/bin/env python3

from PyGMO import *
hv = hypervolume([[2,1,1] , [1,2,1], [1,1,2]])
print(hv.compute(r = [3.5]*3, algorithm = hv_algorithm.hv3d()))
```

Although I have certainly installed the 'pygmo' module, I will face the following error when I run this script.

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/Hype1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PyGMO import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyGMO'*
```

[image]

Note that when "python3 -v", the below list will appear:
[image]
[image]

Comment: run "python3 -v" . it'll print the location of every python module installed in your env. you probably have more than one env installed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As per your suggestion, I ran "python3 -v". A very long list appeared. Accordingly, I update the original post.

Comment: so this shows you where python is searching for your module: /usr/lib/python3.8 . can you find your module there? have you installed it using the same pip3 mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

On our linux server I get the same error typing:

```
from PyGMO import *
```

But I get no error when typing:

```
from pygmo import *
```

Linux is key sensitive, so it makes a difference if you use capital letters.